# What does the lettering mean?

Tags: meaning, word

Thanks for your help <3[image]

The sweatshirt has underneath the letters a weapon and underneath that "Paris" written so I´m a little concerned and confused on what it could mean... ^^´

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um... That picture is mirrored.

犯罪 (fàn zuì) A verb that means "to commit a crime"

Comment: reading from other direction is 罪犯( criminal )

Comment: I don't think 犯罪 can be used as a noun. A crime or criminal offence is translated more appropriately as 罪行. (犯 here means "to commit" and 罪 means "crime", so 犯罪 means "to commit a crime". It is inherently a verb.)

Comment: @YiFan thats a fair point, I'll change my answer. I honestly don't know the word, I just looked it up in a dictionary.